# (Native Module) Android scan bluetooth device return empty array

Tags: android, react-native, android-bluetooth

i've been stuck for a week, i want to make an app that can connect to other android device via bluetooth but cannot discover any devices as it just return empty array.

This is code that i use to discover other android bluetooth devices:

```
public class BluetoothScannerModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private List<BluetoothDevice> discoveredDevices = new ArrayList<>();

    public BluetoothScannerModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        reactContext.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "BluetoothScannerModule";
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (device != null && !discoveredDevices.contains(device)) {
                    discoveredDevices.add(device);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @ReactMethod
    public void scanDevices(Callback callback) {
        discoveredDevices.clear();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            callback.invoke("Bluetooth not supported");
            return;
        }
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            callback.invoke("Bluetooth not enabled");
            return;
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getCurrentActivity(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getCurrentActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, 2);
                return;
            }
        }
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000); // scan for 5 seconds
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        WritableArray devicesArray = Arguments.createArray();
        for (BluetoothDevice device : discoveredDevices) {
            WritableMap deviceMap = Arguments.createMap();
            deviceMap.putString("name", device.getName());
            deviceMap.putString("address", device.getAddress());
            deviceMap.putInt("bondState", device.getBondState());
            devicesArray.pushMap(deviceMap);
        }
        callback.invoke(null, devicesArray);
    }
}
```

and log it into react native like this to see the list of devices:

```
BluetoothScannerModule.scanDevices((error, devices) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
          }
          console.log(devices);
        })
```

**EDITED CODE**

In the Native Module:

```
@ReactMethod
    public void scanDevices(Callback callback) {
        discoveredDevices.clear();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            callback.invoke("Bluetooth not supported");
            return;
        }
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            callback.invoke("Bluetooth not enabled");
            return;
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getCurrentActivity(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getCurrentActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, 2);
                return;
            }
        }
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

        callback.invoke(null,"Discovery started");
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void stopScan(Callback callback) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getCurrentActivity(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getCurrentActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, 2);
                return;
            }
        }
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        WritableArray devicesArray = Arguments.createArray();
        for (BluetoothDevice device : discoveredDevices) {
            WritableMap deviceMap = Arguments.createMap();
            deviceMap.putString("name", device.getName());
            deviceMap.putString("address", device.getAddress());
            deviceMap.putInt("bondState", device.getBondState());
            devicesArray.pushMap(deviceMap);
        }
        callback.invoke(null, devicesArray);
    }
```

In React Native:

```
type Device = {
  name: string | null;
  address: string;
  bondState: number;
};

const [devices, setDevices] = useState<Device[]>([]);

const startDiscovery = () => {
    BluetoothScannerModule.scanDevices((error: string | null, result: string) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
};

const cancelDiscovery = () => {
  BluetoothScannerModule.stopScan((error: string | null, result: Device[]) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      setDevices(result);
    }
  });
};

const renderDevice = ({ item }: { item: Device }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>{item.name ?? 'Unnamed device'}</Text>
    <Text>{item.address}</Text>
    <Text>Bond state: {item.bondState}</Text>
  </View>
);

...

<Button
   title='Start Scan'
   color="#841584"
   accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
   onPress={startDiscovery}
/>
<Button
   title='Stop Scan'
   color="#841584"
   accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
   onPress={cancelDiscovery}
/>
<FlatList data={devices} renderItem={renderDevice} />
```

Android Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [startDiscovery() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#startDiscovery()) says the discovery process usually takes 12 seconds. But you are calling [cancelDiscovery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#cancelDiscovery()) after 5 seconds. So this cannot work.

Also when you call `Thread.sleep(5000)` in these 5s the `onReceive` of the `BroadcastReceiver` cannot be called. Because `onReceive` runs on the main thread. you have to remove `Thread.sleep(5000)`.

Also you may need premissions [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) and [BLUETOOTH_ADMIN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#BLUETOOTH_ADMIN). Also you maybe have to set `usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"`. Please read the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#startDiscovery()).

**Update**:
Request permissions like this (add [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) and [BLUETOOTH_CONNECT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)). Also don't do a SDK version check (it's not necessary):

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getCurrentActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getCurrentActivity(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getCurrentActivity(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getCurrentActivity(), new String[] {
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN }, 2);
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, so far I already added the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` in the manifests. I will need to separate the cancel discovery process to stop the scanning since need to remove the `Thread.sleep(5000)` and retrieve the list right?

Comment: @newlearner Your code looks better now. But you are still not requesting ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. See my update.

Comment: I've added it from your update and at least progress something, but just now if i click the Stop Scan to `cancelDiscovery()`, it give error `Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for android.content.AttributionSource@15db4abf:AdapterService getRemoteName`, does this mean i manage to scan a device and just need some code to handle connect?

Comment: @newlearner I don't know where this comes from. But I edited my post... take a look...

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, finally it get to discover a devices with bluetooth enable nearby, that last one really solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled/added android permissions in the manifest file? requesting to grand a permission and having that permission declared in the manifest file are both important. permissions like **BLUETOOTH_SCAN**, **BLUETOOTH_ADMIN** and location permissions like **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION**, location permissions are important for discovering devices nearby. Also the the phone's location and Bluetooth should also be enabled before starting scan. if you want to connect to a device then you need **BLUETOOTH_CONNECT**,**BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE** also.

I would recommend stop scan on a button press because in most apps you want to scan devices until you connect to one. and scan for a while like 10 to 15 seconds.

Try putting these permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file on top after the line where your package name is. and keep the code intended otherwise it won't work.

```html
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: Hai thank you so much for the response, all the permissions have been added and i separated the code so can do `cancelDiscovery()` but cannot find any devices so far in the application.

Comment: @newlearner if you are using react native try react native BLE library. it's comparatively simpler. I've worked with it and it helps a lot with BLE implementations in react native .

Comment: oh haven't try it yet, just for this project I'm using the native module, next time will try the BLE library. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: its react-native BLE manager to be specific. ble-plx is good and more easier for simpler tasks but it's not that rich in functionality. for simple tasks you can use ble-plx too but i recommend, react native BLE manager.

Comment: i'll be sure to check it both for future use, thank you so much!